# Will I have more control over my spider if I use lxml over BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am learning to make spiders and crawlers. This spidering is my passion and I am going to do that for a long time. For parsing I am thinking of using BeautifulSoup. But some people say that if I use lxml, I will have more control.

Now I don't know much. But I am ready to work hard even if using lxml is harder. But if that gives me full control then I am ready for it.

So what is your opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really think this question makes a whole lot of sense.  You need to give more explanation of what exactly your goals are.  `BeautifulSoup` and `lxml` are two tools that in large part do the same things, but have different features and API philosophies and structure.

It's not a matter of "which gives you more control," but rather "which is the right tool for the job?"  I use both.  I prefer the `BeautifulSoup` syntax, as I find it more natural, but I find that `lxml` is better when I'm trying to parse unknown quantities on the fly based on variables--e.g., generating XPath strings that include variable values, which I will then use to extract specific elements from varying pages.

So really, it depends on what you're trying to do.

#### TL;DR

I find `BeautifulSoup` easier and more natural to use but `lxml` ultimately to be more powerful and versatile.  Also, `lxml` wins the speed contest, no question.

Comment: so u mean , if i use lxml can do anything without the need of Beautiful Soup. Sp learning lxml alone will be enough

Comment: If you learn `BeautifulSoup`, you can also do anything without needing `lxml`.  That wasn't quite what I meant.

Comment: ACtually i understood , what you mean but i need to stick with one but i am not able to decide which one. but if BS is easy i think i can strat with it and then i can see if i need lxml or not